# Using Native Modules with webworkers

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, concurrency, electron

So I'm looking at using node-serialport to communicate with a USB device in Electron. I'm relatively inexperienced with concurrency (especially in javascript), and I'm wondering what the best way to approach things is.

Electron's documentation says NOT to use native node modules with webworkers because most modules are designed and implemented with only one thread in mind. My question is, what exactly is a native node.js module, as apposed to non native (if such a thing even exists), and what is the best way to go about using them asynchronously? I've done some reading on asynchronous computing in Javascript/Node but there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to how I should approach something like this

Edit: sorry I should've added linked to the electron documentation to begin with 
[Electron Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading)

Comment: Important distinction: "asynchronous" does not mean "concurrent". In a web browser, JavaScript is asynchronous (event-based) but single threaded (no concurrency whatsoever). Web workers can mimic multithreading without any race conditions.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Only single-threaded on browsers *within a given realm*. You can have as many threads as you want (within reason) via web workers, but they'll each be in their own realm.

Comment: Carl - It would be useful if you linked to the part of the Electron documentation you're talking about (and if you quoted it verbatim).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Completely true, but the point is OP is mixing up those two terms and using them interchangeably. Electron documentation says not to use them with concurrent threads, but the question OP is asking is "what is the best way to go about using them asynchronously".

Comment: Sorry about that I added a link to said documentation.